# Ajax populating dropdowns not working in IE

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cross-browser

I have been wrestling with some code for the past few days, and I have made no progress.  I need help.  Here is what I am trying to do:

- Manually populate the first of two drop down lists
- Grab the selected value of the first, use it to query a database, populate the second 
  dropdown with the results of the query.
- Use a button to trigger another function to generate a PDF.

I have this code on my site, and working.  The catch is that it is only working in FF and Chrome.  I can not get the dropdown list to populate in IE.  For testing, I have stripped the code to practically nothing just to see if IE will populate the second dropdown list, and it does not.  Below is the code for the test pages:

test.htm:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showCMB2(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
  document.getElementById("cmb2").innerHTML="";
  return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    document.getElementById("cmb2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="cmb1" id="cmb1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />

<input type="button" value="Retrieve Data"   
 OnClick="showCMB2(cmb1.options[cmb1.selectedIndex].value)"> 
<br><br><br>
<span name="cmb2" id="cmb2"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
echo '<select name="cmb2" id="cmb2">';
echo '<option value="cmb2">This is test</option>';
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Like I said, this works great in FF and Chrome, but not in IE.  The span in test.htm with an id of cmb2 I have tried making it  and even a , there was no change in behavior.  Can anyone offer any insight?  This seems so simple.

Comment: IE (at least older versions) doesn't let you modify select contents (adding `<option>`s dynamically) so what you have to do is delete the entire `<select>` and put a new one in.

Answer (score 0):

Your response from the server is trying to add an element with the same id as you've assigned to the span element - ids have to be unique..

Answer (score 0):

Setting innerHTML just does not work properly in IE8. Instead use the jquery function  $('#elementId').html('  .... ');

Note that you MUST have the value= attribute or, when IE passed the option value to another javascript function, it will pass null.